# Change column width in SharePoint 2013 Content is disabled!

Tags: site-column

I want to change column width, and I use this script like in answer:

[Adjust column width in sharepoint 2013](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/eab8a3ca-1a91-45ca-b7d5-a5f78592083e/adjust-column-width-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointgeneral)

It helps, but every time I click this site or refresh it, I've got attention message:

[image]

How can I do it more clever? Is there any other simply script?

I need to change width of this column:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That alert is coming from `http` protocol and your site is being loaded securely using `https` protocol. That is why the browser is blocking the content loading of that jQuery library file. You need to always click on that alert button or else you can place that jQuery library in your `Style Library` folder and then change the absolute reference in your code.

As an alternative you can load jQuery library securely with following URL:

`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js`

Answer (score 1):

Try using local reference for JS instead of cdn reference in following line:

```
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"
```

Comment: how can I do it?

Comment: Download jquery,min,js and upload it to style library to your SharePoint site. Now copy the path to the JS file stored in style library and paste in in src=""

Answer (score 1):

Since your are using OOB list page which is app part in SP2013 and whatever the script you added is in different web or app part, all calls are over cross domain calls for the respective page. So if you want to get rid of this situtaion you have to change all link address from http protocal to https protocal.

```
$(function () {
if (window.location.protocol == "https:") {
    $("a[href*='http']").each(function (i) {
        var nLink = $(this).attr('href').replace('http:', 'https:');
        $(this).attr('href', nLink);
    });
}
});
```

or simple make your src as "https"
use src="**https**://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"

Answer (score 0):

Best way to fix it is delete http or https this way:

src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js